# Counter variable not increasing inside of if statement

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement

I have a function that is suppose to capitalize the first letter of the next word.
***"this is a! Test."*** is the desired result.

```
var splitUp = ["this", "is", "a!", "test."];
```

I increment the variable inside the "for loop" only if the "if" statement runs.

```
if (punctuation.indexOf(translationString[iii]) != -1) {
  console.log(iii+ ": " +translationString[iii]);
  console.log("iii is on: " + iii);
  iii + 2;
  console.log("after increment, iii is on: " + iii);
  translationString[iii].toUpperCase();
}
```

I can not figure out the reason the value of "iii" is not increasing.  Is there a work around or am I missing something entirely?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzmoznuj/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the value back into your variable:

```
//What you're doing:
iii + 2 // The value of iii + 2.  Won't update iii

//What you want to do:
iii += 2 // assign the value of iii + 2 back into your iterator.
```

In the example you posted, you are simply giving the computer some math for the hell of it: iii + 2.  It crunches iii + 2 and moves on; essentially it's a no-op.

> The += operator is shorthand for increment the left by what's on the right.
>
> ie. iii += 2 is equivalent to iii = iii + 2

Answer (score 0):

> iii + 2; // This only adds 2 to the value for a new assignment, that is, it would be something like this:
>
> var iii = 1;
>
> var other = iii + 2; // The value of other is now 3 (1 + 2)

To increase you must use an increment operator:

> iii ++; //Increases the value of iii one each time
>
> iii + = 2 or iii = iii + 2; //Increase the value of iii 2 each time, that is, it would be 2, 4, 6, 8, ...

```
var splitUp = ["this", "is", "a!", "test."];

if (punctuation.indexOf(translationString[iii]) != -1) {
  console.log(iii+ ": " +translationString[iii]);
  console.log("iii is on: " + iii);
  iii += 2;
  console.log("after increment, iii is on: " + iii);
  translationString[iii].toUpperCase();
}

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) 
{
   return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

---

```
var capitalizeTest = capitalizeFirstLetter(splitUp[splitUp.length - 1]);
```